# Calculating true positive and true negative from sensitivity and specificity

Tags: biostatistics, sensitivity-specificity

I know the specificity and sensitivity of a test are both 90%. The incidence is 2.5%.
The total population is 10,000 and the number of people with the illness is 250, how do I calculate the true positive, true negative, false positive and false negative values?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated!
$$
\text{sensitivity} = P(\hat Y = 1\vert Y=1) \\
\text{specificity} = P(\hat Y = 0\vert Y=0) \\
$$
Can you make some progress using Bayes' theorem?

Comment: So what number of the $250$ with the illness do you expect to test positive?  What number of the $9750$ not with the illness do you expect to test negative?